# Merging 3 key=>value arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i have these 3 arrays

Global array

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(1) "4" } 
           [1]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(1) "6" } 
           [2]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "16" } 
           [3]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "17" } 
           [4]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "20" } }
```

Local array

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "13" } }
```

Country array

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "19" } }
```

and when i merge all 3 i get this

Result array

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "19" } 
           [1]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(1) "6" } 
           [2]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "16" } 
           [3]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "17" } 
           [4]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "20" } }
```

However this is what i want

```
array(7) { [0]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "19" } 
           [1]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(1) "6" } 
           [2]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "16" } 
           [3]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "17" } 
           [4]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "20" }
           [5]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "4" }
           [6]=> array(1) { ["shout_id"]=> string(2) "13" } }
```

For some reason it is missing out the values 4 and 13 and i can't work out why.

Here is the code for combining the arrays

```
$result_array = $country_array + $global_array + $local_array;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_merge`, it concatenates arrays with numeric keys.

```
$result_array = array_merge($country_array, $global_array, $local_array);
```

`+` replaces elements with the same key.

Comment: thankyou for your answer that worked great, just out of interest is there any way to remove the multi-dimensinal effect on the result array, by that i mean remove the `array(1)` from each `key=>value`, so it is just the `key=>value` in one array?

Comment: No, because all the keys are the same. Keys in an associative array have to be different.

Comment: If you'd like `array(19, 6, 16, 17.20, 4, 13)` without the `shout_id=>`, that would be possible.

Comment: i just saw a comment that was removed for some reason but they provided this code `$result_array = array_map(current, $result_array);` which works, however i do get a notice of `Notice: Use of undefined constant current - assumed 'current'`

Comment: It should be `array_map('current', $result_array)`.

Comment: that works great and provides this result `array(7) { [0]=> string(2) "19" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "6" [3]=> string(2) "16" [4]=> string(2) "17" [5]=> string(2) "20" [6]=> string(2) "13" }` which makes working with the array much easier

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result_array = array_merge($country_array, $global_array, $local_array);
```

What you're doing is called the 'union' operator in PHP.
It merges the arrays based in their keys (see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php for more info).

And because you have numeric keys (for example three times the key 0) they will be overwritten.